# Scanner class validation

Tags: java, validation, menu

I am having a bit difficulty with my code.  After depositing an amount $30, it is suppose to bring back the Saving Menu 
A- Deposit 
B - Withdraw 
C - Report 
D-Return Main menu

Somehow it keeps scanning $30 instead of asking a new input.

Thanks to anyone who will try helping me out.

```
package Menu;

import java.util.Scanner;

enum Options {
    A, B, C, D
}

public class Menu {
    public Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        menu.mainMenu();
    }

    public void mainMenu() {
        String userChoice;
        boolean quit = false;

        do {
            System.out.println("Bank Menu" + "\nA: Savings" + "\nB: Checking"
                    + "\nC: Exit");

            userChoice = sc.next().toUpperCase();

            switch (userChoice) {
            case "A":
                savingMenu savMen = new savingMenu();
                break;
            case "B":
                break;
            case "C":
                quit = true;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Wrong entry.");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println();

        } while (!quit);
        sc.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

package Menu;

import Savings.Savings;

public class savingMenu extends Menu {
    Savings sav = new Savings();

    public savingMenu() {
        String userChoice;
        boolean quit = false;

        /**
         * A - Deposit B - Withdraw C - Report D - Return Menu
         */
        do {
            System.out.println("Savings Menu" + "\nA: Deposit "
                    + "\nB: Withdraw" + "\nC: Report"
                    + "\nD: Return to Bank Menu");

            userChoice = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            switch (userChoice) {
            case "A":
                sav.makeDeposit();              
                break;
            case "B":
                sav.makeWithdraw();
                break;
            case "C":
                sav.doMonthlyReport();
            case "D":
                quit = true;
                super.mainMenu();
            default:
                System.out.println("Wrong choice.");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println();

        } while (!quit);
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is more than 4 classes... simplify the code you post to the suspicious part only.... so we can help you faster....

Comment: Ok I removed 2 classes (the calculations)

Comment: what does the output look like? can you paste what the command line looks like?

Comment: Right now... I keep getting my exception.

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
 at Menu.savingMenu.<init>(savingMenu.java:20)
 at Menu.Menu.mainMenu(Menu.java:29)
 at Menu.Menu.main(Menu.java:14)

Answer (score 0):

With Scanner check there is a next line with `hasNextLine()`

Comment: I can add this before the switch and it will go infinite loop.
`if(sc.hasNextLine()) {
userChoice = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the error or I should say mis-understanding.

One of my class that I deleted in the post was actually causing the havoc.

```
public void validateDepositAmount() {       
    boolean isDoubleDigit = false;

    System.out.println("How much would you like to deposit?");

    //try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {                            
            if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
                totalDeposit = sc.nextDouble();

                if(totalDeposit >= 0) {
                    isDoubleDigit = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Your input must higher than 0.");
                    sc.nextLine();
                }                   
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please put an amount.");
                sc.nextLine();                  
            }
        } while (isDoubleDigit == false);   
    //} catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    //}
}
```

So basically I was using Try with resources and it just kept going in a loop.